# Switching from EVR to VMR with GMFBridge

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net, ms-media-foundation

I am using GMFBridge for smooth transition between videos. My tests have two monitor, I am using EVR to play a video stretched on all monitors and two VMR's to display different videos on each monitor.

The transition between VMR to VMR and EVR to EVR run very smooth. The problem is when I have an EVR playing and need to change to the two VMR's. If I don't stop the EVR, it continue displaying on the screen, even after the call to GmfBridgeController.BridgeGraphs(null, null).

When switching from VMR to EVR, I don't have to stop the renderers, but I got some 1 second flickering at the start.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point video renderers allocate resources on hardware, esp. Direct3D devices, and this initialization is not instant, and causes some delay or flickering. When you bridge, your strategy should be to keep video renderer and its hosting graph, and switch stuff behind it. This gets you smooth and flicker-less operation.

Switching VMR to EVR (reason?) is unlikely to be smooth. Or, just keep both running at all times and just put one in front of the other as needed.

Comment: The reason I'm switching between VMR and EVR is, according to my tests, because (correct me if I'm wrong) VMR has better performance when playing three different videos on three different monitors. However, EVR can play one video stretched on three monitors, something VMR cannot do.

I tried to keep both running, but I don't know how to "hide" one presenter. Tried the SetVideoWindow with IntPtr.Zero, but it gives me an exception.

Comment: Makes sense. You can hide the renderer with hiding the form/control which hosts it. You might find it convenient to host this by a dedicated control, which in turn is integrated into app UI. Then show/hide the control should do the trick.